# Why Pandas doesn´t allow multiple index setting?

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I am trying to set a multi Index on my office computer

```
data.set_index(['POM', 'DTM'],inplace = True)
```

but I get the following error

```
Categorical levels must be unique
```

At home I don't get the error. Both Pandas are version 0.13.1

Here is some sample data

```
    POM DTM RNF WET HMD TMP DEW INF
0    QuintaVilar    2011-11-01 00:00:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
1    QuintaVilar    2011-11-01 00:15:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
2    QuintaVilar    2011-11-01 00:30:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
3    QuintaVilar    2011-11-01 00:45:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
4    QuintaVilar    2011-11-01 01:00:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
5    QuintaVilar    2011-11-01 01:15:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
6    QuintaVilar    2011-11-01 01:30:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Could you help me?

Thank you

Comment: you need to post sample data here

Comment: I just did. POM is object and DTM datetime

Comment: This works fine for me in 0.13.1, what are the different systems?

Comment: Windows XP, ok. Mac OS Mavericks, error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't be. But how about just creating a `MultiIndex`?:

```
In [52]:

print df
           POM                  DTM  RNF  WET  HMD  TMP  DEW  INF
0  QuintaVilar  2011-11-01 00:00:00    0    0    0    0    0    0
1  QuintaVilar  2011-11-01 00:15:00    0    0    0    0    0    0
2  QuintaVilar  2011-11-01 00:30:00    0    0    0    0    0    0
3  QuintaVilar  2011-11-01 00:45:00    0    0    0    0    0    0
4  QuintaVilar  2011-11-01 01:00:00    0    0    0    0    0    0
5  QuintaVilar  2011-11-01 01:15:00    0    0    0    0    0    0
6  QuintaVilar  2011-11-01 01:30:00    0    0    0    0    0    0

[7 rows x 8 columns]
In [53]:

idx=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df[['POM','DTM']].values.T)
In [54]:

df.index=idx
In [56]:

print df
                                         POM                  DTM  RNF  WET  \
QuintaVilar 2011-11-01 00:00:00  QuintaVilar  2011-11-01 00:00:00    0    0   
            2011-11-01 00:15:00  QuintaVilar  2011-11-01 00:15:00    0    0   
            2011-11-01 00:30:00  QuintaVilar  2011-11-01 00:30:00    0    0   
            2011-11-01 00:45:00  QuintaVilar  2011-11-01 00:45:00    0    0   
            2011-11-01 01:00:00  QuintaVilar  2011-11-01 01:00:00    0    0   
            2011-11-01 01:15:00  QuintaVilar  2011-11-01 01:15:00    0    0   
            2011-11-01 01:30:00  QuintaVilar  2011-11-01 01:30:00    0    0   

                                 HMD  TMP  DEW  INF  
QuintaVilar 2011-11-01 00:00:00    0    0    0    0  
            2011-11-01 00:15:00    0    0    0    0  
            2011-11-01 00:30:00    0    0    0    0  
            2011-11-01 00:45:00    0    0    0    0  
            2011-11-01 01:00:00    0    0    0    0  
            2011-11-01 01:15:00    0    0    0    0  
            2011-11-01 01:30:00    0    0    0    0  

[7 rows x 8 columns]
```